# Not able to have my JavaScript objects to appear in separate columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, bootstrap-4

I I am not able to have my 2 Javascript objects appear in separate columns on the DOM. I am supposed to have a 2 Column page that displays the first person details one side and the 2nd person details on the opposite side

I've tried using a loop to append to the div columns I created. I have a div container in the body with two separate id's to append to.

```js
sabio.page.startUp = () => {

  people = [{
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 23,
      "streetAddress": "123 Main St.",
      "city": "Culver City",
      "state": "CA",
      "zip": 92340
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Juan",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 47,
      "streetAddress": "123 Main St.",
      "city": "Culver City",
      "state": "CA",
      "zip": 92340
    }
  ]
  console.log(people);

  sabio.page.mapObjFunc(people);
}



sabio.page.mapObjFunc = person => {
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

    console.log(i);
    $("#div" + i).append("<h1>" + i + ": " + people[i] + "</h1>");
    people[i] + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="div0">
      <h1>Column 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="div1">
      <h1>Column 2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The expected out come is to my 2 people object's appear on the DOM in two separate columns. I am not getting any error messages, when going live with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in the people array are objects.
You need to enumerate the properties of each object.
Here is the modified code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  let p = people[i];
  let info = '<div>';
  for (let k in p) {
     info += k + ' ' + p[k] + '<br>'
  }
  info += '</div>';
  $("#div" + i).append("<h1>" + i + ": " + info + "</h1>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why there's a break tag underneath your append line.
  Plus, you have closed already your append function.

Maybe you mean like this?

```
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        $("#div" + i).append("<h1>" + i + ": " + people[i] + "</h1><br>");
        //people[i] + "<br>"; <-- This is an error
  }
```